# Which bluetooth module should I buy?

Tags: arduino-mega, bluetooth

I am doing a wireless rover using arduino mega 2560 that can be controlled by a smartphone and a PC. Which bluetooth module would fit me? Again I want to control it both by my Laptop(Built-in Bluetooth) and my smartphone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which smartphone. iOS is pretty strict in what kind of Bluetooth modules it supports.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but in case someone like me ran into this:

**HC-05** seems to be the DIY choice. Can work in slave or master mode and works with Android but not iOS.

**HC-06** is the same as HC-05 except that you can only use it in slave mode.

**HM-10** seems to be the option for iOS users.